# I have an overview map that is not "square on" in the main map

Tags: map-overviews

I am using QGIS version 3.16.6-Hannover.
I have a map with four overviews. Three of the four are square on, but one needs rotation as is obvious by the guide lines in the image.

I have googled my problem with no result.

Any ideas please?

[image: Overview that is not square on]

Answer (score 0):

Check the following under 'Item Properties' in your Layout manager

- Main Properties >  Map rotation - Should be 0 degree's
- Also check the CRS - make sure this aligns with the other overviews.

Also check the 'Rotation' option.

Comment: Thanks so much @nr_aus!